# Publishing and Configuring ASP.NET site in internet

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-6, port, publishing

there!
I'm now publishing asp.net site on test server. I have added it in IIS ( v6.0). I have created for it alias like test.inventory.site.com. On it exists MS Windows Server 2003.
Also I have access to production server. For both servers I connect through Remote Desktop. And to prod. server I connect with address like inventory.site.com, to test server connection address is inventory.site.com:port. I need access through internet to my test site by it's name test.inventory.site.com. On production server exist several sites, therefore it doesn't work when I create alias for production server ip in my local hosts file.
How I can configure it?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your local dns server or on the development box edit the hosts file located in c:\windodws\system32\drivers\etc

You can change the IP address for the host names so that you can point them to your development or live.

The hosts file will just change the address for the site on your local computer.